# How to join sprites in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I have this sprites in Unity and I want to join a head to a body and a gun but I only find tutorials on how to splice. How can I do it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an empty game object and make your sprites children of that game object.

So like this:

```
GameObject (Parent)
   Head
   Gun
   Body
```

If you want to edit the sprite itself, you can use photo editing programs like Photoshop or Aseprite. If you don't have those, you can use [Photopea](https://www.photopea.com)

Comment: I found simplier to make head children of body. Is there any problem?

Comment: No that would be okay but if you ever want to destroy the head, you can't. Because it will destroy all the objects.